# How to refactor test classes that extend JUnit classes

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-jar-plugin

We are using classifiers in our builds to distinguish our artifacts.  The problem is that we are also using the maven-jar plugin to create a test-jar which has some test classes we use elsewhere.  Since the `test-jar` goal uses classifiers to distinguish these artifacts, we get a conflict.

Looking at the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html), `test-jar` is not the preferred way of distributing test classes.  The test classes we want to re-use extend JUnit classes.  So if I put them in their own non-test module, then their test cases won't run, but if I put them in their own module in the test directory, then I'm in the same situation where I'm creating the jar with `test-jar` goal.

How do I refactor these classes such that I can still run them in JUnit from the original location, and re-use them elsewhere?